Creating an Archive page in SPO, but am unsure how to limit the items in the default view
I am currently making an archive page that will hold all of our news articles. I have dynamic filtering set up, so users can select which year of articles they want to view. Is there a way to limit the default view of the page to only display items of the current year until a different year is selected?
